# Creating a Dataflow connection to ODBC in Power BI service

Tags: powerbi

I already created the ODBC drive on my laptop and tested the connection, which works fine. Also, I can connect to the database using an excel file with ODBC.

I'm struggling it setting up a new dataflow connection to an ODBC data source in the Power BI service.

What should I type in each field in the image attached? And what option should I choose as well?

I know the ODBC connection string should be something like: Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; but it isn't working.

Thanks all!

[image]

- create a odbc driver with user and password
- create a dataflow calling that odbc drivers

the expected result is: a new dataflow pulling data from the odbc connection (power bi service, not desktop)